# Sorting out the API traffic in Jmeter

Tags: http, jmeter, traffic

I am beginner on Jmeter and many parts is complicated to understand. When I use "HTTP Test Script Recorder" to record my test script in Jmeter, it records a lot of API traffic calls. How to understand or sort out what API calls I needed, important for my Test Script?
is there any rules or tips for sorting out it?

[image: API call traffic]

I am trying to look through call by call and figure out what each call means (HTTP request, method, response...)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need both `googleadservices.com` and `google.com` (as long as you're not a Google employee who is doing performance testing of these services)

If you create a Recording test plan from the [template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) the requests to Google services (at lest the most popular ones) will be excluded from the recording scope

[image]

When it comes to "rules" and "tips" I can think of 2 major ones:

1. Make sure that your test is targeting **only the system under test**, all 3rd-party images, banners, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. should be excluded
2. Each JMeter thread (virtual user) must behave exactly like a [real user using the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) when it comes to handling:

   - embedded resources
   - [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
   - [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
   - [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)
   - etc.